# Sum of $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^\alpha}\left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I got stuck trying to calculate the following sum: $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^\alpha}\left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}\right)$$ where $\alpha > -1$  (this ensures that the sum converges). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's the same as $\sum\limits_{j=0}^\infty (-1)^j \zeta(\alpha+2+j)$, but does it help?

Comment: Thanks for the observation, but I do not know how to use it to get the end result...

Comment: @MetodJazbec: what is *the end result*? Such series does not appear to have a nice closed form for any $\alpha>-1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm on the bus so I can't reason well. In any case the series reads also

$$\sum_{k = 1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{k^{\alpha}}\frac{1}{k(k+1)}$$

Which you may majorize just to have an idea of its behaviour:

$$\sum_{k = 1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{k^{\alpha}}\frac{1}{k(k+1)} \leq \sum_{k = 1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{k^{\alpha}}\frac{1}{k^2} = \zeta(2+\alpha)$$

Where $\zeta(p)$ is the Riemann Zeta Function.

Comment: Courtesy of [Jack D'Aurizio's PDFs](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxKdOVsjsuEwdjBEM1dpRkhMa2s/view), we know the closely related series:$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k(k+1)^n}=n-\sum_{k=2}^n\zeta(k)$$See page 7.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt What a cute pdf, although there is nothing "superior". Elementary maths one learns in Analysis 1. Thanks for the input anyway!